What Project Reference Variables should be used for .NET Console .exe output
I'm using WixToolset.Sdk/5.0.1
When referencing a .NET Core Console App from the installer, the var.ProjectName.TargetPath variable points to the .dll file.
I need to register the application as a Windows Service so I need the .exe file. At the moment I construct it manually:
  <?define ExeName ="$(var.ProjectName.TargetName).exe"?>
  <?define ExeFullPath ="$(var.ProjectName.TargetDir)$(var.ExeName)"?>

Is there a better way?
